# returning aligned memory with new?

Tags: c++, alignment

I currently allocate my memory for arrays using the MS specific mm_malloc. I align the memory, as I'm doing some heavy duty math and the vectorization takes advantage of the alignment. I was wondering if anyone knows how to overload the new operator to do the same thing, as I feel dirty malloc'ing everywhere (and would eventually like to also compile on Linux)? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, it's important to note that `new` and `delete` can be overloaded either globally, or just for a single class. Both cases are shown in [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/tic/tic0139.shtml). Also important to note is that if you overload `new` you almost certainly also want to overload `delete`.

There are a few important notes about `operator new` and `operator delete`:

1. The C++ standard requires that a valid pointer is returned even if the size passed to it is 0.
2. There's also `operator new[]` and `operator delete[]`, so don't forget about overloading those.
3. Derived classes inherit `operator new` and its brethren, so make sure to override those.

In *Effective C++*, item 8, Scott Meyers includes some pseudocodish examples:

```
void * operator new(size_t size)        // your operator new might
{                                       // take additional params
  if (size == 0) {                      // handle 0-byte requests
    size = 1;                           // by treating them as
  }                                     // 1-byte requests
  while (1) {
    attempt to allocate size bytes;
    if (the allocation was successful)
      return (a pointer to the memory);

    // allocation was unsuccessful; find out what the
    // current error-handling function is (see Item 7)
    new_handler globalHandler = set_new_handler(0);
    set_new_handler(globalHandler);

    if (globalHandler) (*globalHandler)();
    else throw std::bad_alloc();
  }
}


void operator delete(void *rawMemory)
{
  if (rawMemory == 0) return;    // do nothing if the null
                                 // pointer is being deleted
  deallocate the memory pointed to by rawMemory;
  return;
}
```

For more information, I'd definitely pick up *Effective C++*.

Comment: so, would I just put that in a header and reference that header in all of my files?

Comment: Well, you'd put the definitions in a source file, but yes.

Comment: just a small footnote: you can also define an `operator new(size_t count, size_t alignment)` so you can explicitly pass the alignment as an argument to operator new. This would be called as `new (alignment) AlignedType`

Comment: @user666412 be aware that this conflicts with the signature for placement new. A better one would be    operator new(size_t count, size_t address, size_t alignment)

Comment: @Tom Lint .. isn't the signature for placement new a `(size_t, void *)`?

Comment: @user666412 You are correct. My example signature should've been
    operator new(size_t count, void * address, size_t alignment)

Answer (score 3):

`new` is required to return a `pointer [...] suitably aligned so that it can be converted to a pointer of any complete object type` (§3.7.3.1 of the standard).

FWIW, C++ 0x will add an `alignof` that will tell you the alignment necessary for a particular type.

Comment: Unfortunately, for some reason I've never really understood, compilers don't generally apply this rule for 128-bit SIMD types. They're typically still `new`'ed with 8-byte alignment I believe.

Comment: @jalf: two reasons: (1) the more aligned allocations are, the greater the allocation overhead per block. If you make a lot of 17-byte allocations, you'd see a difference between 16-aligning them and only 4-aligning them. (2) (GNU-specific), glibc makes fewer platform-specific assumptions than GCC, and doesn't really know or care what the biggest type is that some compiler on a system might support. But GCC "wants" to pass malloc straight to glibc, not add its own alignment mechanism, with even more overhead than malloc doing it. I read an interesting public argument about it somewhere.

Comment: ... finally, the compiler could in theory choose to just align calls to `new SIMD_Type`, avoiding the overhead on all allocations over 15 bytes. But that would still be wrong, because if you're going to do that then you should also similarly align calls to `new char[sizeof(SIMD_Type)]`. The consensus is to pretend that SIMD types aren't "proper builtin types", they're special things that must be allocated specially.