# How to align array of structs, each require alignment (SSE)

Tags: c++, malloc, memory-alignment

I have a `struct alignedStruct`, and it **requires** special alignment (SEE ext):

```
void* operator new(size_t i) { return _aligned_malloc(i, 16); }
void operator delete(void* p) { _aligned_free(p); }
```

This alignment works fine for unique objects/pointers of `alignedStruct`, but then I tried to do this:

```
alignedStruct * arr = new alignedStruct[count];
```

My application crashes, and the problem is definitely about "alignment of array" (exactly at previous line):

```
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFF.
```

Such crash occur in ~60% of times, also indicates problem is not typical.

Comment: possible duplicate of [returning aligned memory with new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660076/returning-aligned-memory-with-new)

Comment: Are you also redefining `operator new[]` and `operator delete[]` as well? Also, why exactly do you **require** special alignment? Is it SSE-related?

Comment: yes! :P How to override new[] correctly? I need this i think

Comment: @Mgetz Don't you understand my question about array? alignment which question there is about i already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [placement `new`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) which allows you to use the `_aligned_malloc` with a constructor properly. Alternatively you can [overload `operator new[]` and `operator delete[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660076/returning-aligned-memory-with-new).

```
void* operator new[] (std::size_t size)
{
   void * mem = _aligned_malloc(size, 16);
   if(mem == nullptr)
      throw std::bad_alloc;
   return mem;
}
```

Comment: I need new[] not new override i think.

Comment: @Loryan55 placement new works for both (minor syntax differences), and I've provided an example of how to overload `new[]`

Comment: Thanks, missed that knowledge.